# How to swap the entire node in a linked list such that it swaps every single information within that node

Tags: sorting, swap

I am currently trying to sort the linked according to the phone numbers and my sorting alogrithm sorts the phone numbers, however it only swaps the phone numbers it does not swap the entire node itself. This is is my linked list struct

```
struct List
{
   char*firstName;
    char*lastName;
    char*phoneNumbers;
    struct List*next;
}
typedef struct  List list;
```

I know  exactly why this is happening because in my swap function I am only swaping the phone numbers and the not everything else. I have been trying for hours, but I just don't seem to be getting anywhere. Am I missing something???

```
void insertSort(list*theList)
{
    int swapped;
    list *ptr1;
    list *lptr = NULL;

    ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(list));

    if (ptr1 == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        ptr1 = theList;

        while (ptr1->next != lptr)
        {
            if (strcmp(ptr1->phoneNumbers,ptr1->next->phoneNumbers) > 0)
            {
                swap(ptr1, ptr1->next);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            ptr1 = ptr1->next;
        }
        lptr = ptr1;
    }
    while (swapped);
}
void swap (list*elementOne, list*elementTwo)
{
    char*temp;

    temp = elementOne->phoneNumbers;

    elementOne->phoneNumbers = elementTwo->phoneNumbers;

    elementTwo->phoneNumbers= temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite swap function like this :

```
void swap (list *elementOne, list *elementTwo) {
    list* temp = elementTwo;
    elementTwo = elementOne;
    elementOne = temp;
}
```

This should work, assumption is insertSort is correct.

Comment: I tried the exact same thing earlier and it doesn't sort at all unfortunately. Maybe my insertSort is incorrect.